# SwiftData with UIKit - Data is lost and errors are thrown when I save different models

Tags: swift, uikit, swift-data

I have a bag model and a disc model. The disc can be added to a "cart" or a "bag"

The issue I am getting is when I save a disc to the cart. It saves but completely deletes all of my bags I created previously. I am using the new SwiftData and I think it is the way I am handling the data.

Also, please note I am sometimes (50% of the time) getting an error saving a disc to the cart. see the error below:

> error: (1) I/O error for database at
> /Users/kinneykare/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/598D3C68-FEB3-4D2C-AE97-FA7B58D4CD0D/data/Containers/Data/Application/591F6E15-E5E9-4624-8267-DB838828D807/Library/Application
> Support/default.store.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table:
> ZDISCSWIFTDATAMODEL' error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception
> handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600003b0ed80> , I/O
> error for database at
> /Users/kinneykare/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/598D3C68-FEB3-4D2C-AE97-FA7B58D4CD0D/data/Containers/Data/Application/591F6E15-E5E9-4624-8267-DB838828D807/Library/Application
> Support/default.store.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table:
> ZDISCSWIFTDATAMODEL' with userInfo of {
> NSFilePath = "/Users/kinneykare/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/598D3C68-FEB3-4D2C-AE97-FA7B58D4CD0D/data/Containers/Data/Application/591F6E15-E5E9-4624-8267-DB838828D807/Library/Application
> Support/default.store";
> NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1; }

Here is the updated file that handles CRUD for discs and bags as well as the SwiftData:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftData

class DatabaseService {
    static let shared = DatabaseService()

    private var discContext: ModelContext?
    private var bagContext: ModelContext?

    private init() {
        do {
            discContext = try ModelContainer(for: DiscSwiftDataModel.self).map(ModelContext.init)
            bagContext = try ModelContainer(for: BagSwiftDataModel.self).map(ModelContext.init)
        } catch {
            print("Swift Data Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // MARK: Discs

    func saveDisc(
        discName: String,
        discImageData: Data,
        discStability: String,
        discSpeed: String,
        discGlide: String,
        discTurn: String,
        discFade: String,
        discBrand: String,
        viewController: UIViewController
    ) {
        saveData(
            context: discContext,
            data: DiscSwiftDataModel(
                id: UUID().uuidString,
                name: discName,
                imageData: discImageData,
                stability: discStability,
                speed: discSpeed,
                glide: discGlide,
                turn: discTurn,
                fade: discFade,
                brand: discBrand
            ),
            viewController: viewController
        )
    }

    func fetchDiscList(onCompletion: @escaping ([DiscSwiftDataModel]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        fetchData(context: discContext, descriptor: FetchDescriptor<DiscSwiftDataModel>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor<DiscSwiftDataModel>(\.brand)]), onCompletion: onCompletion)
    }

    func updateDisc(disc: DiscSwiftDataModel, newDiscName: String) {
        updateData(data: disc, updateBlock: { $0.name = newDiscName }, context: discContext)
    }

    func deleteDisc(disc: DiscSwiftDataModel) {
        deleteData(data: disc, context: discContext)
    }

    // MARK: Bags

    func saveBag(bagName: String, bagType: String, bagHexColor: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
        saveData(
            context: bagContext,
            data: BagSwiftDataModel(
                id: UUID().uuidString,
                bagHexColor: bagHexColor,
                bagTitle: bagName,
                bagType: bagType
            ),
            viewController: viewController
        )
    }

    func fetchBagList(onCompletion: @escaping ([BagSwiftDataModel]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        fetchData(context: bagContext, descriptor: FetchDescriptor<BagSwiftDataModel>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor<BagSwiftDataModel>(\.bagTitle)]), onCompletion: onCompletion)
    }

    func updateBag(bag: BagSwiftDataModel, with disc: DiscGolfDisc) {
        updateData(data: bag, updateBlock: { $0.discs.append(disc) }, context: bagContext)
    }

    func removeDiscFromBag(disc: DiscGolfDisc, from bag: BagSwiftDataModel) {
        if let index = bag.discs.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == disc.id }) {
            bag.discs.remove(at: index)
            updateData(data: bag, updateBlock: { _ in }, context: bagContext)
        }
    }

    func deleteBag(bag: BagSwiftDataModel) {
        deleteData(data: bag, context: bagContext)
    }

    // MARK: Generic Functions

    private func saveData<T: Storable>(context: ModelContext?, data: T, viewController: UIViewController) {
        guard let context = context else {
            print("ERROR SAVING DATA!")
            // Show an alert to the user
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "An error occurred while saving the data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        context.insert(data)
    }

    private func fetchData<T: Storable>(
        context: ModelContext?,
        descriptor: FetchDescriptor<T>,
        onCompletion: @escaping ([T]?, Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        guard let context = context else {
            onCompletion(nil, NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }

        do {
            let data = try context.fetch(descriptor)
            onCompletion(data, nil)
        } catch {
            onCompletion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    private func updateData<T: Storable>(data: T, updateBlock: (T) -> Void, context: ModelContext?) {
        guard let context = context else { return }
        updateBlock(data)
    }

    private func deleteData<T: Storable>(data: T, context: ModelContext?) {
        guard let context = context else { return }
        context.delete(data)
    }
}
```

Here is how I am saving my disc:

First there is a delegate:

```
import UIKit

protocol AddDiscToViewDelegate {
    func dissmiss()
    func saveDiscToCart()
    func saveDiscToBag()
}

class AddDiscToView: UIView {

    var delegate: AddDiscToViewDelegate?
    
    @IBAction func addToCartTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Send user to fillout form then pop to view
        delegate?.saveDiscToCart()
        delegate?.dissmiss()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func addToBagTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Send user to fillout form then pop to view
        delegate?.saveDiscToBag()
        delegate?.dissmiss()
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Cancel Tapped")
        delegate?.dissmiss()
    }   
}
```

Next there is a viewController that the call is actually fired at.

```
import UIKit

class DiscViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var discNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var discImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var glideLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var turnLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fadeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var discView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!    
    @IBOutlet weak var simularDiscsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
       
    var dropDownView: AddDiscToView!
    var disc: DiscGolfDisc?
    var similarDiscs: [DiscGolfDisc] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        setupCollectionView()
        setupAddDiscToView()
        
        // Add a "Select All" button to the navigation bar
        let selectAllButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "plus"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addDiscTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectAllButton
    }
    
    private func setupAddDiscToView() {
        dropDownView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddDiscToView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as? AddDiscToView
        
        dropDownView.delegate = self
        dropDownView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainView.addSubview(dropDownView)
        dropDownView.isHidden = true
        
        dropDownView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        dropDownView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
        dropDownView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 249).isActive = true
        dropDownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func setupCollectionView() {
        simularDiscsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        simularDiscsCollectionView.delegate = self
        
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        // Set the scroll direction to horizontal
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        // Calculate the item width based on your desired width
        let itemWidth: CGFloat = 200.0 // Adjust this value to your preferred width
        
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: simularDiscsCollectionView.frame.height)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0 // Adjust spacing between items
        
        simularDiscsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    }
  
    
    @objc private func addDiscTapped() {
        dropDownView.isHidden.toggle()
    } 
}


extension DiscViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return similarDiscs.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscCell
        
        let disc = similarDiscs[indexPath.item]
        
        cell.similarDiscNameBottomLabel.text =  disc.name
        
        getImageFromLink(imageView: cell.discImageView, disc: disc)
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        disc = similarDiscs[indexPath.item]
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.createSimilarDiscsCollection(disc: self.disc)
            self.setupFlightPathAnimationView()
        }
    }
}

extension DiscViewController: AddDiscToViewDelegate {
    func saveDiscToBag() {
        
        BagDatabaseService.shared.fetchDiscBagList { [weak self] bags, error in
            guard let self else { return }
            if error == nil, bags == [] || bags == nil  {
                K.showAlert(title: "No Bags Created", message: "You need to add a bag before you can add a disc to your bags. Click the bag tab and tap the + to add your first bag.", presentingViewController: self)
            } else {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "AddDiscToBag", bundle: nil)
                
                if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addDiscToBagVC") as? AddDiscToBagViewController, let disc = disc {
                    vc.disc = disc
                    dropDownView.isHidden = true
                    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
                    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveDiscToCart() {
        
        guard let disc = disc else {
            K.showAlertWithRetryOption(title: "Issues Getting Disc Data", message: "We ran into a problem attempting to get the disc's data.", presentingViewController: self) { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self else { return }
                self.saveDiscToCart()
            }
            return
        }
        
        if let image = discImageView.image {
            if let imageData = image.pngData() {
                SwiftSpinner.show(delay: 3, title: "Saving Disc To Cart!", animated: true)
                DiscDatabaseService.shared.saveDisc(discName: disc.name, discImageData: imageData, discStability: disc.stability, discSpeed: disc.speed, discGlide: disc.glide, discTurn: disc.turn, discFade: disc.fade, discBrand: disc.brand, viewController: self)
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            }
        } else {
            K.showAlert(title: "Issues Saving Disc", message: "We ran into a problem attempting to save the disc.", presentingViewController: self)
            SwiftSpinner.hide()
        }
    }
    
    
    func dissmiss() {
        dropDownView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I think you should drop the whole idea with your XDatabaseService classes but if you still want to use them you should definitely first create _one_ ModelContainer instance and then inject it into your service classes so they all use the same container. The use of multiple containers is most likely the reason you loose  data and get error messages.

Comment: Why would you recommend I drop this way?

Comment: Updating separate model context for each model can lead to issues with data inconsistency (and crashes) if you have relationships between them. It also looks like you have a lot of duplicate code and unnecessary code to maintain where you can easily do the same thing outside of such a service or by using a common generic service with functions that can be used for all models.

Comment: So are you saying to throw them in the same file to reduce duplicated code? I know I can make the CRUD functions reusable later but I am more so talking about the rest of the code: 


I will edit what I think you are saying above